# What is Parser Error?

Tags: error, parser

What is Parser Error? How to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: Upload your contract please so we can see where the error is.

Comment: how to upload my contact?

Comment: Copy-paste it in your question. BTW, your problem is a missing `}` before or after that line of code.